# Spectral Saliency map from Matlab code to C#.net,

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, aforge, spectrum

[SSM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU1cu.png)

Hi, I have implemeted the Spectral Saliency map from Matlab code to C#.net,
But result is some strange.
Result map is not correctly mapped to original image.

What's wrong with me?

Original Matlab code(Octave) is here:

```
%% Read image from file
inImg = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('1.jpg')));
inImg = imresize(inImg, 64/size(inImg, 2));

%% Spectral Residual
myFFT = fft2(inImg);
myLogAmplitude = log(abs(myFFT));
myPhase = angle(myFFT);
mySpectralResidual = myLogAmplitude - imfilter(myLogAmplitude, fspecial('average', 3), 'replicate');
saliencyMap = abs(ifft2(exp(mySpectralResidual + i*myPhase))).^2;

%% After Effect
saliencyMap = mat2gray(imfilter(saliencyMap, fspecial('gaussian', [10, 10], 2.5)));
imshow(saliencyMap);
```

My Code is here : C#.net + AForge.net -------------
Windows10, VS2017, AForge & Accord.net

```
// 이미지 로드
image2 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
// 박스 블러
// logAmp smoothing
Accord.Imaging.Filters.FastBoxBlur filtBox1 =
new Accord.Imaging.Filters.FastBoxBlur(3, 3);
// apply the filter
filtBox1.ApplyInPlace(image2);

// 크기줄이기 64x
AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear filtResize =
new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ResizeBilinear(64, 64);
// apply the filter
Bitmap smallImage = filtResize.Apply(image2);

// 2D FFT -------------------------------------------
//cv::merge(planes, 2, complexImg);
AForge.Imaging.ComplexImage complexImage =
AForge.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(smallImage);

//double[,] logAmpl = new double[64, 64];
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
//Calculating elementwise complex conjugate of the shifted image 2d vector
complexImage.Data[x, y].Im = 0;
}
}// for y

//cv::dft(complexImg, complexImg);
complexImage.ForwardFourierTransform();

// Calc Log AmpliTude of magnitude
double[,] logAmpl = new double[64, 64];
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
//Calculating elementwise complex conjugate of the shifted image 2d vector
logAmpl[x, y] = Math.Log(Complex.Multiply(
complexImage.Data[x, y], complexImage.Data[x, y]).Magnitude);
}
}// for y

Bitmap logAmp = logAmpl.ToBitmap();

// extract Phase, int[,] array = new int[4, 2];
double[,] myPhase = new double[64, 64];
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
//Calculating elementwise complex conjugate of the shifted image 2d vector
myPhase[x, y] = complexImage.Data[x, y].Phase;
}
}// for y

// calc Spectral Residual -------------------------
// logAmp smoothing
Accord.Imaging.Filters.FastBoxBlur filtBox =
new Accord.Imaging.Filters.FastBoxBlur(3, 3);
// apply the filter
Bitmap smoothAmp= filtBox.Apply(logAmp);

// subtraction
AForge.Imaging.Filters.Subtract filter =
new AForge.Imaging.Filters.Subtract(smoothAmp);
// apply the filter
Bitmap specResi = filter.Apply(logAmp);

// Calc Saliency map -----------------
// residual for Re
AForge.Imaging.ComplexImage totalSpec =
AForge.Imaging.ComplexImage.FromBitmap(specResi);

// + j*im
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
totalSpec.Data[x, y].Im = myPhase[x, y];
}
}// for y

// exp of re + j*im
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
totalSpec.Data[x, y] = Complex.Exp(totalSpec.Data[x, y]);
}
}// for y

// ifft2
//complexImage.ForwardFourierTransform();
totalSpec.ForwardFourierTransform();

// .^2 of ifft2
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
{
totalSpec.Data[x, y] =
Complex.Multiply(totalSpec.Data[x, y], totalSpec.Data[x, y]);
}
}// for y

// abs .^2
Bitmap salMap= totalSpec.ToBitmap();

// 가우시안 블러
Accord.Imaging.Filters.GaussianBlur filt2 =
new Accord.Imaging.Filters.GaussianBlur(2.5, 9);
// apply the filter
filt2.ApplyInPlace(salMap);

// create filter
Accord.Imaging.Filters.ContrastStretch filtNorm =
new Accord.Imaging.Filters.ContrastStretch();
// process image
filtNorm.ApplyInPlace(salMap);

//ImageBox.Show(salMap);
pictureBox3.Image = salMap;
```

What;s wrong with me?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with you, and with your code neither unless you explain how the result is diverging from your expectations.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my question.